# 4096 single line character limit on tkinter Text() widget?

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, tkinter

I've run into an interesting issue regarding the `Text` widget in Tkinter I can't seem to understand. Google has provided no answers either. It seems like Tkinter has a single line character limit on the `Text()` widget of 4096 character when text wrapping is disabled. Is there a way to change this limit or force a text wrap after 4095 characters? I've seen the `wraplength` parameter on other widgets but nothing for the `Text` widget.

Example code:

```
import Tkinter as tk

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    text = tk.Text(root)
    sb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="horizontal", command=text.xview)
    text.configure(xscrollcommand=sb.set)
    text.configure(wrap=tk.NONE)
    text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    sb.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

    text.insert("end","a"*4095)
    text.insert("end","\n")
    text.insert("end","b"*4096)
    text.insert("end","\n")
    text.insert("end","c"*4095)

    root.mainloop()
```

What's really strange is if you click or highlight where the "b"s should be printed they show up all of sudden? Why did they disappear in the first place?

Python version: 2.7.5

OS: Windows 7

UPDATE:

This seems to be a platform issue with Windows 7. Still not sure why it occurs or if it can be remedied easily.

Screenshots:

This is what the application looks like when first started. 'b's are missing:

[image]

Once I give the 'b's focus they show up all of sudden:

[image]

Once I remove focus from the 'b's they disappear.

Comment: What platform are you running this on? I see the extra "b" when I run the code on OSX.

Comment: Operating system: Windows 7

Comment: This appears to be a windows platform issue: your code works on my Fedora Linux system (and the other guy says it works on Mac). You may wish to tag it as such?

Comment: Can't reproduce on Vista (Python 2.7.5) and Windows 7 Enterprise (Python 2.7.6) - on both machines I see the extra "b".

Comment: No problem with 4096, but when I put 5000 `b`s in the line, the last few hundred `b`s overlay the first ones (i.e. they are neither truncated not wrapped, but overwrite the first few `b`s _on the same line_, making them look blurred and bold). Tested on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Added screenshots to the OP. I'm seeing this issue on numerous PCs.

Comment: Can anyone else confirm they are seeing this issue? This may be an OS setting unique to the systems I'm working with.

Comment: @Matt I see the exact same thing as you, Python 2.7.8 on Windows 7 x64, however the b's appear normally when I scroll at least two characters to the right

Comment: No problem on Win 8, Python 2.7.8

Answer (score -1):

i have found a partial solution on another site:
[here](http://forums.devshed.com/python-programming-11/tkinter-text-wraplength-266931.html)

it works by subclassing the text widget to watch the line length and insert an extra newline character when the limit is reached

```
import Tkinter as tk

class WrapText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, master, wraplength=100, **kw):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, master, **kw)
        self.bind("<Any-Key>", self.check)
        self.wraplength = wraplength-1 

    def check(self, event=None):
        line, column = self.index(tk.INSERT).split('.')
        if event and event.keysym in ["BackSpace","Return"]: pass
        elif int(column) > self.wraplength: 
            self.insert("%s.%s" % (line,column),"\n")

    def wrap_insert(self, index, text):
        for char in text:
            self.check()
            self.insert(index, char)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    text = WrapText(root, wraplength=4000)
    sb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="horizontal", command=text.xview)
    text.configure(xscrollcommand=sb.set)
    text.configure(wrap=tk.NONE)
    text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    sb.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

##    text.tag_config("mystyle", background="yellow", foreground="red", wrap="char")

    text.wrap_insert("end","a"*4095)#,"mystyle")
    text.wrap_insert("end","\n")
    text.wrap_insert("end","b"*4095)
    text.wrap_insert("end","\n")
    text.wrap_insert("end","c"*4095)

    root.mainloop()
```

this method has several obvious limitations, firstly it is actually adding characters to the data that is being entered (which may not be desirable) and secondly it only wraps by character, so it could wrap in the middle of a word, but there are ways in which this could be implemented aswell.